# Indexing not working when large data affected in where condition

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a query. As follows

```
SELECT  SUM(principalBalance) as pos, COUNT(id) as TotalCases,
        SUM(amountPaid) as paid, COUNT(amountPaid) as paidCount,
        SUM(amountPdc) as Pdc, SUM(amountPtp), COUNT(amountPtp)
    FROM  caseDetails USE INDEX (updatedAt_caseDetails)
    WHERE  updatedAt BETWEEN '2016/06/01 00:00:00' AND '2016/06/30 23:59:00'
```

It uses indexing effectively. Screen shot of result of explain:[image: Result of explain]
There are 154500 records in date range '2016/06/01 00:00:00' AND '2016/07/26 23:59:00'.

But when I increase data range as,

`SELECT SUM(principalBalance) as pos, COUNT(id) as TotalCases, SUM(amountPaid) as paid, COUNT(amountPaid) as paidCount, SUM(amountPdc) as Pdc, SUM(amountPtp), COUNT(amountPtp) FROM caseDetails USE INDEX (updatedAt_caseDetails) WHERE updatedAt BETWEEN '2016/06/01 00:00:00' AND '2016/07/30 23:59:00'`

Now this is not using indexing. Screen shot of result of explain:[image: Result of explain]
There are 3089464 records in date range '2016/06/01 00:00:00' AND '2016/07/30 23:59:00'

After increasing date range query not using indexing anymore, so it gets too much slow. Even after I am forcing to use index. I am not able to figure out why this is happening as there is no change in query as well as indexing. Can you please help me to know about why this is happening.

Comment: Try `force index` instead of `use index`. But generally, assuming your numbers are correct, summing up 20 times as many rows will of course be slower. So how slow is "much too slow" (compared to the other case)? How many rows do you have in total in that table? It might actually be that a full table scan is faster than 3 million row lookups via the index (unless it is a covering index that includes all columns you use in that query, e.g. `principalBalance`, and thus doesn't need to read the table afterwards).

Comment: Thanks @Solarflare for the input. I have tried this, query uses index but its processing is still slow.

Comment: Yes, as I said, if you have 20 times as many rows (3 million instead of 150k), it is supposed to be slower. If it requires less than 20 times the time than the first query, choosing a different index was a good idea by MySQL, and forcing the index might be slower than before. You could try a full covering index (the index `(update_at, principalBalance, amountPaid, ..., amountPtp)`. It should be faster for this query, but as with all indexes, it will slow down updates/inserts, and will require space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey it has been long time I had ask this question, Now I have better solution for this which is working really smoothly for me. I hope my answer may help someone.

I used `Partitioning` method, and observed that performance of the query is really high now. I alter table by creating range partitioning on `updatedAt` column.

[Range Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-range.html)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `USE INDEX` or `FORCE INDEX`.  This will slow down the query when most of the table is being accessed.  In particular, the Optimizer will decide, *rightly*, to do a table scan if the index seems to point to more than about 20% of the rows.  Using an index involves bouncing back and forth between the index and the data, whereas doing a table scan smoothly reads the data sequentially (albeit having to skip over many of the rows).

There is another solution to the *real* problem.  I assume you are building "reports" summarizing data from a large Data Warehouse table?

Instead of always starting with raw data ('Fact' table), build and maintain a "Summary Table".  For your data, it would probably have 1 row per day.  Each night you would tally the `SUMs` and `COUNTs` for the various things for the day.  Then the 'report' would sum the sums and sum the counts to get the desired tallies for the bigger date range.

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Your 'reports' will run more than 10 times as fast, and you won't even be tempted to `FORCE INDEX`.  After all, 60 rows should be a lot faster than 3089464.

Answer (score 1):

## less time (more likely)

Using an index might be inferior even when disk reads would be fewer (see below). Most disk drives support bulk read. That is, you request data from a certain block/page and from the *n* following pages. This is especially fast for almost all rotating disks, tapes and all other hard drives where accessing data in a sequential manner is more efficient than random access (like ... really more efficient).

Essentially you gain a time advantage by sequential read versus random access.

## fewer disk reads (less likely)

Using an index is effective, when you actually gain speed/efficiency. An index is good, when you reduce the number of disk reads significantly and need less time. When reading the index and reading the resulting rows determined by using the index will result in almost the same disk reads as reading the whole table, usage of an index is probably unwise.

This will probably happen if your data is spread out enough (in respect to search criteria), so that you most likely have to read (almost) all pages/blocks anyway.

## ideas for a fix

if you only access your table in this way (that is, the date is the most important search criteria) it might very much be worth the time to order the data on disk. I believe mysql might provide such a feature ... (optimize table appears to do some of this)

this would decrease query duration for index usage (and the index is more likely to be used)

## alternatives

see post from [Rick James](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46223580/4275413) (essentially: store aggregates instead of repeatedly calculating them)

Comment: Thanks @Jakumi. I will try to collect more info about my server configuration.